# data not getting retrieved from async storage

Tags: react-native

```js
const _retrieveData = async (path) => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(path);
    console.log(value, "value data")
    if (value !== null) {
      return JSON.parse(value)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  setCard1(_retrieveData("foodData0"))
  console.log(card1, "data0")
}, [])
```

I want the code to wait for retrieveData and but I get console log statement first and then data is replaced in card1 any other way I can go about it?
I want to use card1 to retrieve data from DB and thus I am getting card empty error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you are calling an async function and expecting the see the result right away. You need to wait for the result for your async call.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {  
  async function retrieveData(path) {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(path, null);
    if(value){
      setCard1(value);        
    }
  }  
  retrieveData("foodData0");
}, []);
```